# Is it possible to get SharePoint Online usage metrics for one modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-usage, metrics

I know SharePoint Online has usage metrics about the whole site but, is it possible to get some more granularity for each page? I mean, is it possible to get the people that visited the home page or a news page that has been created? I would like to have dates, users (anonymous and logged in people), active time, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Azure Application Insights, absolutely. See Chris O'Brien's post on how to create an SPFx solution to enable this.

[Add Azure App Insights or Google Analytics to your SharePoint pages with an SPFx Application Customizer](https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/08/SPFx-App-Insights.html)